# How to clean up long MySQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array from which I need to insert into a MySQL database. I've already discovered that appending each value to the query has had massive performance improvements rather than an INSERT for each row.

The only thing is it feels a bit messy - there's lots of string concatenation and then the comma needs removing at the end, not to mention combining 100+ rows into one string means a rather large variable! Any ideas on how to improve this, it does work but is just feels very messy? Here is a simplified version of how it is currently working.

```
$insertData = "INSERT INTO table (x,y) VALUES ";

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $insertData .= "($value[0],$value[1]), ";
}

$insertData = rtrim($insertData,", ");
$conn->query($insertData);
```

Comment: If the values are coming from the outside, e.g. from a UI, then you should probably use a prepared statement here.  If the values are _not_ coming from the outside, or you can verify that they are safe (e.g. just integers), then there should be nothing wrong with your approach.  Messy is not a big issue if it performs well.

Comment: Also, if you run into memory problems because of the size of the string (which is unlikely, unless it is really a lot of data), you could write into a file and use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html).

Comment: If it ain't broke...